# Change name of Program Files

Tags: windows, filenames

Is there any way to change the name of *Program Files* folder of Windows? Its annoying in certain circumstances since there's a space within the name.

Windows 7 or any other versions of Windows.

Comment: You will do this **once** in your lifetime and forevermore regret it afterwards till you replace the system, never to repeat the same mistake. Plus `cd "\program files\something or other...` just needs an opening quote. Windows shell will fill in the end quote automatically. The joke is that given most programs out there today, you've only eliminated one space for 64 bit and two for x86 folders for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

While it is technically possible to change the name, more than likely you would break the system.  Since `Program Files` is Windows system folder, many programs simply ***expect*** it to be there.  By removing it, you can break your existing application and prevent new ones from working. Changing the folder name is just a *very* bad idea all around.

However, one possibility is using the `subst` command

> subst G: "c:\program files"

FYI, here is the help output for `subst`:

> Associates a path with a drive letter.
>
> SUBST [drive1: [drive2:]path]
>   SUBST drive1: /D
>
> drive1:        Specifies a virtual drive to which you want to assign a path.
>    [drive2:]path  Specifies a physical drive and path you want to assign to
>                   a virtual drive.
>    /D             Deletes a substituted (virtual) drive.
>
> Type SUBST with no parameters to display a list of current virtual drives.

You can assign a drive letter to a path.  This means you can use G:\ instead of "c:\program files"  I do not see any reason this wont work, but if you start using it, you will be committed to it.  If you stop using it, any programs using G:\ will no longer function properly and you will have to change registry settings, configuration files, etc... for all your applications.

I ***strongly*** recommend to leave it as it is and deal with the space.

Comment: What I do is create a [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) to it named `ProgramFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the folder name mean changing the path of programs that are already installed.The programs already installed may not work properly or may not work at all.